# Como pesquisar perguntas negativadas que sairam da home?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Após uma pergunta levar quatro downvotes ela saia da home. Como faço para achar uma lista dessas perguntas?

Answer (score 4):

Na caixa de pesquisa digite:

```
is:question score:<..-4
```

Por último deixe na aba recentes.

**Referência:**

[Is it possible to search for down voted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156150/238766)

[Add search option for down voted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156466/238766) (Aqui tem mais alguns exemplo de usos)

Comment: Engraçado que não lembro de nenhum lugar do site que tenha essa informação dos `..`

Comment: Engraçado que la não esta documentado, mas aparentemente `>` tem o mesmo efeito que `<`